# Static data member definition with global member ambiguity

Tags: c++

When x is a global variable as well as a static variable in class while defining the static member of class, ambiguity as below is seen.

```
ambiguity.cpp
using namespace std;

int z = 100;

int x = 100;

class WithStatic {

    static int x;
    static int y;
    static int a;

    public:

        void print() const {
            cout << "WithStatic::x = " << x << endl;
            cout << "WithStatic::y = " << y << endl;
            cout << "WithStatic::a = " << a << endl;
        }
};

int WithStatic::x = 1;
int WithStatic::y = x + 1;
int WithStatic::a= z+1;

int main() {
    WithStatic ws;
    ws.print();
}
```

Output:

```
WithStatic::x = 1

WithStatic::y = 2

WithStatic::a = 101
```

I have a problem at defining `y`. Why is global `x` not taken instead? `WithStatic::x` is taken.
Why is the output of y not equal to 101 , instead of 2?

Comment: What's your problem? If looks fine to me. your static y should be 2, and that's what you are outputting...

Comment: @Developer My question is that why y is not equal to 101 .

Comment: I would also have expected that to be 101.

Answer (score 4):

### From [n4567](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf)

#### 9.4 Static members [class.static]

Paragraph 3:

> A static member may be referred to directly in the scope of its class or in the scope of a class derived (Clause 10) from its class; in this case, the static member is referred to as if a qualified-id expression was used, with the nested-name-specifier of the qualified-id naming the class scope from which the static member is referenced.

```
// Example:
int g();
struct X
{
    static int g();
};
struct Y : X
{
    static int i;
};
int Y::i = g(); // equivalent to Y::g();
```

Comment: But how is it explaining  the ambiguity ?

Comment: @Malik: Yes I hate standardease as well. But the point is to be very price in the meaning (but the example (from the standard) is supposed to help for those are not standardease experts). But from the may I read this (and I could be wrong): because `Y::i` is a static member of the `Y` thus when it is initialized we are initializing it from within the scope of `Y` and namelookup is done from there. Which means `g()` is searched for from that context and thus we check for (in this order) `Y::g()`, `::g()` (note we search because we did not refer to it directly).